# Loop through slicer items using VBA

Tags: vba, pivot

I want to loop select all slicer items within a certain range . Let's say , all items from `3` to `6` . My slicer contains the following items `1 , 2, 3, 5, 6, 8`

Here is what I tried

```
Sub SlicerTest()

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_rtytr")

    Dim maxNumberOfDays As Long
    maxNumberOfDays = 9    'I want to be able to identify the number of items programmatically but do not know how to do this     
    Dim fromDay As Long
    fromDay = 3

    Dim toDay As Long
    toDay = 6            

    For i = 1 To maxNumberOfDays

        If (i > fromDay And i < toDay) Then
            .SlicerItems(CStr(i)).Selected = True
        Else
            .SlicerItems(CStr(i)).Selected = False
        End If    
     Next i

End With

End Sub
```

The result should be that the slicer picks only `5` but it throws an error . I tried a regular `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` array and it works fine . I guess this one does not work because of missed values ?

Answer (score 2):

This article explains what you need, and some.

https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/accessing-the-slicer-through-vba/

The relevant bit:

```
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem

Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(“Slicer_Dates_Hie”)
Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

Debug.Print “——————————————————————————“

For Each sI In SL.SlicerItems

    Debug.Print “Caption –> ” & sI.Caption
    Debug.Print “Value –> ” + CStr(sI.Value)
    Debug.Print “Unique Name –> ” + sI.Name
    Debug.Print “——————————————————————————“

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that a normal array works (normal being quantified as containing 9 elements in an array in this context) is because you specify that you want to loop from 1 to 9 in this line here `For i = 1 To maxNumberOfDays`. In your example you only have 6 items so you'll hit an error by trying to access more items than are currently within the array.

I'm not too familiar with slicer objects unfortunately, but, to fix this issue you'll want to know exactly how many items are within your slicer. After a quick look at the documentation on [silcers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301044.aspx) there doesn't appear to be a count property, however, there is a numberOfColumns property. If the column number correlates with how many objects you have (again not entirely sure that it does) then just assign:

`maxNumberOfDays = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_rtytr").numberOfColumns`

If this does not work I would explore other options for figuring out the number of elements that will be within your array.

Comment: Thank You  I decided to count the number of elements in the slicer `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A3:A16,A3:A16,0),MATCH(A3:A16,A3:A16,0))>0,1))` . But the problem is how do I adress the error ? `try and catch` ?

Comment: It's generally bad practice to "expect" an error and try to circumvent it with try-catches. Is that excel query being done programmaticly? If so assign it to your maxNumberOfDays variable. Remember you'll want to dynamically figure out how many elements ( unless you ALWAYS have a static number of elements).